# Programatically start a background process under linux

Tags: linux, console

Is it possible to start a Linux process in background without using `&`, `nohup`, `tmux`, `disown`, `CTRL-Z` + `bg`, what-so-ever.

In another word, what I am looking for is something like the [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) Windows API, detach from console from within the program itself, not by the user of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my python3 source right now.

pseudo python code look like :

```
token = fork()
if ( token == 0 ) :
    close(stdin) ; close(stdour) ; close(stderr)
else :
    print (token)
    return
## actual payload code start here
```

I then can close terminal, ssh connection, forked process will stay.

---

Not closing stdin et al. will prevent terminal/ssh session from exiting.

As a pratical point I mostly repoen stdout to a log file to print debuging/informatinal messages.

---

exerpt from my python3 code

```
    from os import fork, getuid, mkdir, path, unlink

    ## payload code initialisation

    pid=fork()
    if pid > 0 :
            print (f'démon pour {moi} forké avec le pid {pid}')
            pidtxt="/run/user/"+str(getuid())+"/"+moi+".pid"
            if path.isfile(pidtxt) : unlink(pidtxt)
            fpid=open(pidtxt,"w")
            print('{pid}'.format(pid=pid),file=fpid)
            fpid.close()
            exit()

    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stderr.close()
    flog = open("log/"+moi+".log","a",buffering=1)
    sys.stdout = flog
    sys.stderr = flog

    ## payload code run
```

Comment: note that the nice thing about this pseudocode is that it's basically the same for C, and a whole bunch of other languages.

Comment: well `fork(2)` is doing all the job, be it in C or python.

Comment: exactly, that's the point. Still, having a bit of an example is what `man 2 fork` omits (for the `fork(2)` page from the Linux man-pages project)

Comment: You might want to add some further refinements (such as ignoring some signals), and be aware of what happens with a threaded parent.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  except that I am not using python :-)